# Is it possible to UNION two EXECUTE BLOCK statements?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-psql

Is there a way to perform a union of 2 sets where both were output by 2 different execute block commands?

The sets structure are the same but each one contains different parameters therefore I cannot easily merge both in one execute block command.

For example

```
EXECUTE BLOCK RETURNS -- set 1

AS DECLARE VARIABLE....my sql 1

BEGIN
FOR
..... my sql 1
DO
BEGIN
FOR
..... my sql 1 
DO BEGIN
SUSPEND;

END
END
END      UNION

EXECUTE BLOCK RETURNS -- set 2

AS DECLARE VARIABLE....my sql 2

BEGIN
FOR
..... my sql 2
DO
BEGIN
FOR
..... my sql 2 
DO BEGIN
SUSPEND;

END
END
END
```

Comment: Your code suggests that what you have a N + 1 query problem. You might want to check carefully if that is really need (most N + 1 queries can be simplified to a single query by using joins).

Comment: Hi Mark, the N +1 query problem is something new for me, although I might have crossed it occasionally without acknowledging it.  For what I have read,  my query is not what this is about, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXCUTE BLOCK` cannot be used in a `UNION`. Only `SELECT` can participate in a `UNION`. If you want to union the results of two blocks of PSQL, you will need to create them as selectable stored procedures, instead of ephemeral `EXECUTE BLOCK` statements. With two selectable stored procedures, you can then apply `UNION`:

```sql
select * from procedure1
union
select * from procedure2
```

Alternatively, if you really need to use `EXECUTE BLOCK`, then you need to create a single `EXECUTE BLOCK` that creates the full output. I don't see what prevents you from creating a single execute block though: if the parameters differ, then you just need to add separate parameters for either, or - if it is about output parameters - rename things to make them usable by both.

Comment: All right Mark. I thought it would be possible to UNION the EXECUTE BLOCK, but for what you say I might have to review my SQL code in order create a single execute block. Let´s work on it then. Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull It might be an interesting feature. I'll think about adding an improvement ticket to the Firebird issue tracker.

Comment: Great @MarkRotteveel !

Comment: actually, current EB statement is somewhat erratic, it goes `out of tune`. Would there just be `SELECT * from EB` like there is `SELECT * from SP` and there would not be a problem to start with. Except for being chatty, but that is what SQL is about :-)  // Also, @MarkRotteveel , what about using EBs in CTEs ? If it is not possible - then can you add it to the ticket. If it is, then you probably can do UNION of CTEs :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm going to suggest to allow EXECUTE BLOCK where derived tables are allowed, no need for `select * from <execute block>`, maybe just `<execute block>` or `(<execute block>)` should be sufficient; applying as CTE should be possible to.